# How to keep width and height of <td> after setting absolute position on <tr>

Tags: html, css, css-animations

After applying `position: absolute` to a table row (`<tr>`), the row width collapses to have just the content width of the `<td>` elements.

How do I maintain the same width the `<td>` and its elements had before `position: absolute` was applied?

I am interested in this as `position: absolute` is being applied for the purpose of smoothly animating the removal of rows of the table.

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  height: 90px;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>How it is when just applying absolute position</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="position: absolute">
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<h3>This is more like how I want it to be using additional CSS</h3>
<p>
Ideally, the row should <strong>keep the dimensions it had before "position: absolute" was applied</strong> so that it is aligned and <strong>perfectly on top of the row that is below it</strong> in the html.
</p>
<p>
It looks like I need to find the longest string in the column and then simulate that width while using "display: table" to make it work.
</p>
<p>
And also likely need to overwrite some table, table-row CSS defaults to make it match exactly but I am not sure how.
</p>
<table class="full-width">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr
  class="full-width"
  style="position: absolute; display: table;">
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is also a jsfiddle like the code snippet above showing this issue:

- https://jsfiddle.net/a8w6gm27/

The row with "Joe Swanson" should basically be directly on top of the "Cleveland Brown" row with the exact same width and height of each cell but it is collapsed to the absolute minimum of the content.

I've tried applying the all of the possibly related CSS classes that I could think of to the `<tr>` but nothing has worked for me so far.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? when *Joe Swanson* will same all of *Cleaveland Brown*, It will cover the whole row. Can you make an image of the output you really want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Newbee,  I updated the code snippet to also more explicitly show a hardcoded example of what I want to achieve. If what I am trying to do is not yet clear please just let me know and I will make it more explicit.

Comment: Absolute positioning of table rows is an absolute no-go, you can not expect it to retain any of the normal table row "behaviors" after that. Whatever you actually need to achieve here - you'll most likely have to find a way without absolute positioning.

Comment: _"This is more like how I want it to be (hardcoded solution)"_ - if that actually satisfies your requirements here, then "soft-code" it instead. The "removal" is going to involve JavaScript anyway, I'd assume - so read the current cell widths before you apply the absolute positioning, and explicitly set them for the cells.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. I am using Vue and the framework itself applies the absolute positioning when using the <TransitionGroup> component. See this example: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#move-transitions It is used for the duration of the animation when you press the "Remove" button in the example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, so I don't know if there is some way to apply the transitions to the cell contents instead. (If you wrapped all the cell contents into an additional div container each, and then transitioned those divs instead, it should not mess with the row layout.) The documentation also mentions that this can use a wrapper element - of course normally there must be no additional wrapper around a table row, it is a direct child of the tbody. But perhaps trying to specify a wrapper element could still help, if browsers will actually "tolerate" that - worth a try, maybe.

Comment: As I check your sample, you are really want to cover the *Cleaveland Brown*. If that so, I add answer that will nearly of the output you want to achive. If that's not really help you to overcome the problem, just say it so I can improve/remove my answer.

Comment: Hi @Newbee. Thanks for the answer but it would not quite work in my case. I've found that also applying `display: table` along with `position: absolute` solves most of the issues, however, it needs to be combined with the longest strings from all of the columns (will likely need javascript for that) but I still need to figure out which `<table>`, `<th>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` CSS properties I need to define to make it match exactly. I've updated the second table in my code snippet with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it will cover **Cleaveland Brown** cell, But since you agree with that, I will do this that will the same with your explanation. I just added css in your table; locate your cell absolute positioned then add style. But this will not accurate so you can change the height width of the cell depend on your requirement

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  height: 90px;
}

/*.hardcoded-width {
  width: 600px;
}*/

tr:nth-child(3) > td{
  height: 86px;
}
tr:nth-child(3) > td{
  background-color: rgba(135, 206, 235,0.4);
  left:1px;
  width: 204px; /* Change here*/
}
tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2){
  background-color: rgba(135, 206, 235,0.4);
  width: 204px; /* Change here*/
}
tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3){
  background-color: rgba(135, 206, 235,0.4);
  width: 162px; /* Change here*/
}
```

```html
<h3>How it is when just applying absolute position</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="position: absolute">
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```